# Mono.Cecil: Is there a way to tell if an AssemblyDefinition has been modified?

Tags: c#, mono.cecil

I'm using a custom assembly resolver that caches the loaded assemblies (like DefaultAssemblyResolver). I'd like to add a SaveAll method to the resolver that saves all assemblies that have been loaded and changed, but not ones that have been loaded just for things like getting TypeReferences.

I can have the modification code explicitly tell the resolver when it changes an assembly, but I was wondering if there is a way to detect if an AssemblyDefinition is "dirty" automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can just keep a list for the changed assemblies yourself. Or you can just modify the Cecil source code to add some events for code changing status.